# how to change image in android while switching between activities

Tags: android, image, android-activity, switching

in my app in activity A i have a list view showing some details along with an image at the bottom and a button at the top. When the user clicks in the list  it opens a new activity B.

If the user clicks the back button he returns back to activity A and there i want to show a new Image in the image View. At the same time there should not be any change in the activity A.

In iPhone we are to use a method called View will appear.

like that is there any method in android. How to do this, please help me friends.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `startActivity` to start an activity use `startActivityForResult`. 
If you are in Activity A onitemclick event
use the following code to start activity B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WebViewTest.this,
B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 500);
```

write the image updation code inside following method so that when activity B is finished the control comes to the following method. You can use Handler concept also to update image

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println(requestCode + "...called from another activity..."
                + resultCode);
        if (requestCode == 500) {

                //upate image

        }

    }
```

Thanks
Deepak